# Mobile scrolling report

Tags: mobile, scrolling

I had a strange question from a client regarding mobile scrolling. They were concerned about the length of 'pages' and wanted to know whether any reports had been conducted on users fingers or thumb strengths on interacting with scrolling mobile sites. As you can appreciate this is an odd question but has anyone come across any reports or even heard such a request?

Comment: +1. I too am curious. I'd like to add that I'm using the SE mobile application myself and did scroll down to see this question. :) also as a heavy tech user, when doing research on the go I scroll for info all the time in the browser. I understand that this also depends on the demographic and I may not be the persona you need. I think with limited screen space users are more likely to do research on desktop/tablet where there is more screen estate but on mobile it's expected you have to scroll to find what you need..IMHO

Answer (score 1):

There is an interesting blog article [here](http://uxmyths.com/post/654047943/myth-people-dont-scroll) with a bunch of different links to studies on the topics.  Some of this may not be totally up to date, and doesn't just apply to mobile but it's interesting to see the results - for the most part people don't mind scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

Most mobile services have implemented infinite scrolling and I haven't heard any complaints about it yet. Rather than having to click and go to a new page to get information, mobile users will prefer scrolling.

If your page is too long, implement infinite scrolling where a certain portion of the content loads and when the user scrolls to the end of that section, another portion gets loaded. Like Twitter.